# IPV6 dynamic route from DHCP

Tags: 12.04, ipv6, gateway

IPV6 was configured locally in my network in Ubuntu 12.04, where one of my machine runs the DHCP server and other as client. But the client was not acquiring the route from DHCP. Do we have to give route manually for IPV6. IPV4 acquires route from DHCP, is that the same with IPV6.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 auto-configuration has several parts:

- Routing is done with RA (Router Advertisement) messages sent out by the router(s)

  - The RA message may tell the client that stateless auto-configuration is allowed so the client can give itself IPv6 addresses without needing to contact a DHCPv6 server
  - The RA message also informs the clients about if any DHCPv6 servers are present, and of which type.
  - The RA can also contain an indication that the router that sent it can be used as a default gateway.
  - (and there are many more things that can be in an RA, but let's keep it simple for now ;)
- DHCPv6 can be used in two different modes:

  - You can have a DHCPv6 server that does not hand out IPv6 addresses, but that does give extra information like DNS settings, time servers etc. This is called stateless DHCPv6.
  - You can have a 'full' DHCPv6 server that will give out addresses and any other settings. This is called stateful DHCPv6.

Do the routing part is always done by the RA. DHCPv6 does not contain any routing information. The idea behind this is that the router knows better about routing than a DHCPv6 server.

I would recommend starting with one of these scenarios:

- **If you don't really care which addresses each device gets and just want them to be able to access the IPv6 internet:** Let the router send out RA messages that indicate that a stateless DHCPv6 server is available and that stateless auto-configuration is allowed. Configure a stateless DHCPv6 server that provides DNS settings to the clients. The clients will then configure their own addresses based on the information in the RA, use the router as default gateway and they will get their DNS settings from the stateless DHCPv6 server.
- **If you do care about the addresses and want to manage them, when you want to update a DNS server automatically with a client's address etc.:** Let the router send out RA messages that
  indicate that a stateful DHCPv6 server is available and that stateless auto-configuration is not allowed. Configure a full DHCPv6 server that hands out addresses and provides DNS settings to clients. The client will not configure its own addresses, will use the router as default gateway, and will get both addresses and DNS settings from the DHCPv6 server.